# `hyperref' and `biblatex' used with the `combine' package

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, hyperref, combine

I'm facing a hard time getting the `combine` package to work with `biblatex` and `hyperref`. My minimalistic example:

Some article to be included in combine'd document (article-1.tex):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twocolumn]{article}
\input{common}

\title{Some Title}
\date{}
\author[1]{Some Author}
\author[2]{Another Author}
\affil[1]{Some where}
\affil[2]{Else}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is some text, even citing some publicaton: \cite{patrick2011}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My common.tex just contains some macros that should be available in every article:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{cham-literature.bib}

\providecommand*{\taxon}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\providecommand*{\centigrade}[1]{$#1^\circ\textrm{C}$}
\providecommand*{\kelvin}[1]{$#1\textrm{K}$}
\providecommand*{\person}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

The cham-literature.bib file:

```
@article{patrick2011,
        author  = "David A. Patrick AND Philip Shirk AND James R. Vonesh AND Elizabeth B. Harper AND Kim M. Howell",
        title   = "Abundance and Roosting Ecology of Chameleons in the East Usambara Mountains of Tanzania and the Potential Effects of Harvesting",
        journal = "Herpetological Conservation \& Biology",
        year    = "2011",
        volume  = "6",
        number  = "3",
        pages   = "422--431"
}
```

And finally the combining document (sourcing only the one article mentioned above)

```
\documentclass{combine}
\input{common}

\title{Journal 2016-1}
\author{Jan-Benedict Glaw (Hrsg.)}
\date{31. Februar 2016}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{combine}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\begin{papers}
        \coltoctitle{Title 1}
        \coltocauthor{Author 1}
        \import{article-1}
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

This works nicely when I remove all the biblatex and hyperref stuff, but well, that's kind of not what I want. Right now, this results in:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...\undef \blx@dopreamblecmds 
                                                  \let \do \noexpand \expand...
l.11 \begin{document}
```

Would be quite grateful for any help!

Comment: I'm not really surprised. Given that `natbib` and `cite` need special handling and given the acrobatics Biblatex does and given the doctoring to basic stuff done by `hyperref` ... it would be pleasantly astonishing if it all happened to work ;).

Comment: I think that Biblatex undefines various commands at `\begin{document}`. (See `biblatex.sty`.) These include `\blx@dopreamblecmds`. You can surely work around this, but I suspect it is only the beginning of the troubles ....

Comment: Well, going for Bibtex instead of biblatex (would love to keep ist, but I'd let it go), this remains with hyperref:
    `! Undefined control sequence.`
    `\@begindocumenthook ...fi \Hy@AtBeginDocumentHook` 
    `                                                  {}\let \Hy@AtBeginDocument...`
    `l.15 \begin{document}`

Comment: Both `hyperref` and Biblatex redefine a *lot* of LaTeX internals, as does `combine`. There are some suggestions in `combine`'s manual for working around or avoiding errors. Did you try those?

Comment: I finallyy gave up on trying to get `combine` working with anything more complicated than very simple articles (ie. without `hyperref`, `biblatex` etc.) Now building a script to build the articles individually, and later on combining them with `pdfpages` (combined with `pax`) into a final document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I couldn't make `combine' to really work with anything more complex than some simple paragraphs of text.

My solution was to have the articles freestanding as usual, and have (besides all other stuff) this in a central .tex file \input{}ed by every article:

```
\usepackage{catchfile}
\newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{
        \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{}
        \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi
}
```

Within the preamble in each article, I fetch some data from environment variables, ie.:

```
\getenv[\STARTPAGENUMBER]{STARTPAGENUMBER}
\getenv[\PUBLISHEDINIFO]{PUBLISHEDINIFO}
```

used later on to print a publishing info (year, issue, page range) on every article's first page as well as to adjust the starting page number:

```
\begin{document}
\IfInteger{\STARTPAGENUMBER}{
        \setcounter{page}{\STARTPAGENUMBER}
}{}
\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [anchor=north, yshift=-0.8cm] at (current page.north) 
{\PUBLISHEDINIFO};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Another wrapping LaTeX file is prepared to contain cover pages, the TOC etc., and it pulls in all the individual articles:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Article Title}
\includepdf[pages=-]{articles/foo}%.pdf
\clearpage
```

(Actually, it's a central common .tex file \input{}ing generated .tex files containing editorial text, front images, back images, articles etc. All of these imput files are given through environment variables, so this is a solution that works for me and is easily scriptable.)

Comment: Just to be clear, each individual `tex` file needs to contain the first 3 boxes of code, and the combining tex needs to contain only the last one right? I'm getting a `tex capacity exceeded parameter stack size error` unfortunately for some reason with the individual file compilation to PDF after adding this though. The PDF is fine, except it doesn't have references.

Comment: Not sure why you went through so much trouble, but for most people, the steps in [this blog post](https://www.monperrus.net/martin/creating+proceedings+from+pdf+files+with+latex) should suffice. Remove page numbers from the PDFs that needs to be included, and use the `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}` when including PDFs, and you'll get a new PDF with proper page numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to generate conference proceedings using `combine`, with each article being able to use `biblatex`. My solution is below. Additionally, I needed to leave the option to use built-in `thebibliography` environment for some articles. Although I did not have to use `hyperref`, I am sure this solution works for it as well.

### Some lyrical digression

The problem with `\import {subfile}` command from `combine` class given in `main.tex` is that it redefines `\jobname` macro to `subfile`. Additionally, it redirects AUX file output from `main.aux` to `subfile.aux`. This is needed for the labels and citations to be local for each subfile. This also results in redirecting output from `main.bcf` (biblatex auxiliary file) to `subfile.bcf`. This is incompatible with biber as it tries to read `main.bcf`, which becomes partially generated, as well as `subfile.bcf`. I could manage to make biblatex write `subfile.bcf` correcly, but this does not help with typesetting `main.tex` with correct bibliography. I also tried to "patch" `combine` so it would not redirect output to subfiles, but I got even more problems.

Finally, I decided to abandon `\import` altogether in favor of `\input` from `docmute` package (the same functionality from `newclude` package seems to be broken for the long time). I still use `combine` to typeset the table of contents with article titles and authors.

### The solution

The article data are stored in the `newpapers.csv` file with the following structure:

```
<authors to appear in TOC>;<relative path>;<TEX file name>;<BIB file name>
...
```

The directory structure is supposed to be similar to the proceedings volume archive generated by EasyChair.

```latex
\documentclass %
  [ %
    % Options...
  ] %
  {combine}

% Loading other packages...

\usepackage [nomauthor] {combinet}    % table of contents
\usepackage {datatool}    % to read the list of articles from an external file
\usepackage {docmute}     % \input command that reads only document environment
\usepackage {titling}     % to enable using \maketitle many times

\let \bibtexcite \cite    % remembering the original \cite

\usepackage {csquotes}
\usepackage %
  [ %
    % Options...
  ] %
  {biblatex}

\let \biblatexcite \cite

% Loading packages required for included articles...

% Reading biblatex bibliography resources:

\DTLsetseparator {;}

\DTLloaddb %
  [ %
    noheader, %
    keys = {name,relpath,texfile,bibfile}, %
  ] %
  {newpapers} %
  {newpapers.csv}

\def \sominternalmacro {}

\begin {DTLenvforeach*} %
  {newpapers} %
  {\myname=name,\relpath=relpath,\texfile=texfile,\bibfile=bibfile} %
  %
  % Test whether \bibfile is empty
  \ifx \sominternalmacro \bibfile \sominternalmacro
    % Nothing
  \else
    \addbibresource %
      {papers/00010\relpath/\bibfile.bib}
    % EasyChair directory structure
  \fi
  %
\end {DTLenvforeach*}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin {document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------

% Title page, foreword, etc....

\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\let \oldmaketitle \maketitle

% Used to disable adding sections from articles to the TOC
\let \oldaddcontentsline = \addcontentsline

\newcommand {\nocontentsline} [3] %
  {}

\def \maketitle %
{%
  \let \addcontentsline = \oldaddcontentsline
  %
  % Adding the title and authors to the TOC
  %
  \addtocontents %
    {toc} %
    {%
      \protect \contentsline {coltoctitle}%
      {\protect \numberline {}\thetitle} {\thecolpage}%
    }%
  %
  \addcontentsline %
    {toc} %
    {coltocauthor} %
    {\protect \numberline {}\myname}
  %
  \oldmaketitle
  %
  % Disabling adding sections from articles to the TOC
  \let \addcontentsline = \nocontentsline
  %
  % Resetting section numbers for this article
  \setcounter {section} {0}
  \setcounter {subsection} {0}
  \setcounter {figure} {0}
  \setcounter {table} {0}
}%

% Looping over each article:

\begin {DTLenvforeach*} %
  {newpapers} %
  {\myname=name,\relpath=relpath,\texfile=texfile,\bibfile=bibfile} %
  %
  % Some custom definitions...
  %
  \clearpage
  %
  % If bibfile is empty,
  \ifx \sominternalmacro \bibfile \sominternalmacro
    % use the usual LaTeX \cite
    \let \cite \bibtexcite
  \else
    % otherwise, use biblatex \cite
    \let \cite \biblatexcite
    %
    % Start a new biblatex reference section with local references
    \newrefsection %
      [papers/00010\relpath/\bibfile.bib]
  \fi
  %
  % Input the article TEX file
  \input {papers/00010\relpath/\texfile}
  %
  % Other settings...
  %
\end {DTLenvforeach*}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\end {document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I should add that in this solution, other counters should probably be reset along with `section`. Without it, all figures, tables, etc. have the global numbering throughout the collection, which is usually not the desired behavior.

Comment: Added resetting `figure` and `table` counters for each article.